# Is the vector space $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$? How about $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

From Hoffman & Kunze Linear Algebra:[image]

> Is the vector space $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$
>
> Is the vector space $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$?

I am trying to think about this but it is a bit confusing. What is a basis for $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$? Can it be $\{1\}$?

If I try to let $\{1\}$ be a basis then the only elements I can get are $0$ and $1$ since I must have $z\cdot 1$ for $z \in \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: How is $\mathbb R$ a vector space over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$?

Comment: I am not sure. Can it not be?

Comment: @AlJebr Not in any nice way. Consider $\vec x+\vec x=(1+1)\vec x=0\vec x$.

Comment: Well, you have to respect the field structure.  So, for $x\in \mathbb R - \{0\}$ you'd need to have $\vec 0=(0)\times x = (1+1)\times x= x+x$.

Comment: To your second question...at least $\mathbb R$ is a vector space over $\mathbb Q$.  But $\mathbb R$ is uncountable, so not isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$ even as sets.

Comment: In Linear Algebra by Hoffman & Kunze, it says: Every $n$ dimensional vector space over the field $F$ is isomorphic to the space $F^n$. Doesn't this say $\mathbb R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$ if we let $\mathbb R$ be a vector space over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: You can't just "let" anything be a vector space over whatever field you want.  You have to actually say how you are defining the vector space operations and verify that they satisfy the axioms.

Comment: Besides, aren't you missing that little superscript $n$? The text says "isomorphic to $F^{\color{red}{n}}$", not "isomorphic to $F$".

Comment: Well I was thinking that $\mathbb R$ is $1$ dimensional over $\mathbb Z_2$.

Answer (score 7):

1. A vector space structure would require a ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\to \operatorname{End}_\mathbb Z(\mathbb R)$, but the only homomorphism is zero, since the identity of the field of two elements has to map to something with finite additive order.
2. *Is the vector space $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$?* You are apparently asking "isomorphic as $\mathbb Q$ vector spaces." Of course not. One is $1$ dimensional, the other is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb R$ one dimensional over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Why would it be?

Comment: Then give an example of a basis that contains one real. Try to get every real number by multiplying with a rational. Good luck :)

Comment: Ahh I see now. If we pick any finite basis, we will not be able to get every real number by any finite linear combination.